Nodemon not restarting after making changes locally in docker
I want to use nodemon on the docker environment using volume such that if I make any changes locally it will get reflected on the built container.I have tried multiple ways and also did previous stack overflow solution and still didn't get the outcome I was looking for.
This is my dockerfile
FROM node:latest
RUN npm install -g nodemon
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm" , "run" , "dev"]

index.js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.json([{
        id: 1,
        name: "Maadasdsasdasnk",
        age: 205
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Tsar",
        age: 24
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "Vansh",
        age: 21
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: "Aditya",
        age: 22
    }])
});

app.listen(3000, (req,res)=>{
    console.log("Server is running on 3000")
})

package.json
{
  "name": "basic-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "docker tutorial",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon -L index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
  }
}

Command I am using to create volume
docker run --name basic-container -p 3000:3000 --rm -v \Users\Welcome\Desktop\Docker\basic-app:/app basic-app

